# Luigi Central Scheduler significantly slower than --local-scheduler

Tags: python, luigi

I have an extremely simple Luigi luigi.contrib.external_program.ExternalProgramTask. No dependencies on this task. The task simply gets a single input file, passes it to an exe and then a file is written out which completes the task. Each task runs for about 1-4 seconds.

`--workers 8` - 100 tasks takes about 3m20s

`--workers 1 --local-scheduler` - 100 tasks takes about 1m:40s`

This is on my laptop and not "distributed" but I don't understand how the --local-scheduler is substantially faster when Luigi should be scheduling multiple tasks to be running in parallel.

When running with the centralized scheduler I see 8+ python processes pop up and running but the overall process is slower.

Comment: Just a side note, the local scheduler is averaging 1s per task.

Comment: You don't show how you are generating the 100 tasks, but that is likely the issue.